# Issue installing Geos and Gdal on an Amazon Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, gdal, geos, osgeo

I am running an Amazon Ec2 instance with Cent Os Image. I need to install Geos and Gdal to run python scripts.
I first try this guide: https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP/wiki/Geos-installation-on-centos6
And then bind the Gdal installation to it like this:
`sudo ./configure --with-python -with-geos=/usr/local/bin/geos-config`
Unfortunately, when I run the script, I am inform that: **ERROR 6: GEOS support not enabled.**
Even if during the ./configure instance, I get **Geos Enable: Yes**

---

Then I uninstall everything and try installation through yum... and it appears that during the Gdal installation process, I am noticed that the Geos Lib needed is the 3.1.0 (2009 release) when the installed one (through yum as well) is 3.4.2

```
Error: Package: gdal-1.4.4-2.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libgeos-3.1.0.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.4.4-2.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libodbcinst.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.4.4-2.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libpq.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.4.4-2.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libodbc.so.1()(64bit)
```

Is there a way to install a osgeo package that already include everything?

Answer (score 1):

We were able to install gdal and geos successfully on el5 and el6 using the packages from the EPEL repo: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

If you are mixing repositories (which is not recommended), be sure to use includepkgs/exclude in your repo configs, or (better) use the yum priorities plugin to avoid library incompatibilities.

Comment: I did make this try and after a 'sudo yum update' have the unpleasant result to have the terminal asking me for a password. For those about to try to do it the same be aware: [See here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=163327)